# Convert strings with a "-" (En Dashes) into a floats

Tags: python

I would like to convert strings of a Pandas DataFrame into floats. The strings contain "-" (En Dashes), which I believe have prevented me from performing this task.

My DataFrame (df) looks like:

```
Name    LONGITUDE   LATITUDE
0   alta floresta d'oeste   -61.999.824 -1.193.554
1   ariquemes   -63.033.269 -9.908.463
```

I have tried to convert the two columns (LONGITUDE and LATITUDE) into floats with the following code:

```
df_float = df.astype({'LONGITUDE':'float','LATITUDE':'float'})
```

but it gives me this error:

```
could not convert string to float: '-61.999.824'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suppose it is `degrees.minutes.seconds`, and then it shouldn't be converted to `float` this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i thought the string should be made to floats.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["alta floresta d'oeste", "ariquemes"],
        "LONGITUDE" : ["-61.999.824", "-1.193.554"],
        "LATITUDE" : ["-63.033.269", "-9.908.463"]
    }
)

def remove_dot(s):
    s = s.split(".")
    x = s[0] + "." + "".join(s[1:])
    return(x)

new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        df["Name"],
        df["LONGITUDE"].apply(remove_dot),
        df["LATITUDE"].apply(remove_dot)
    ],
    axis = 1
)

new_df = new_df.astype({'LONGITUDE':'float','LATITUDE':'float'})

new_df.head()
```

Gives me this:

| None | Name | LONGITUDE | LATITUDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | alta floresta d'oeste | -61.999824 | -63.033269 |
| 1 | ariquemes | -1.193554 | -9.908463 |

If there are formated in a other way the `remove_dot` function can easily be changed to fit.